# How to temporarly go back to previous versions of your code but preserve the latest changes in Git

Tags: git, github

I have a `Git` repository with 2 tags, named `version-1` and `version-2`. I'm currently working on what would be `version-3` of my app, the code has changed a LOT since `version-2` and I still have a lot of work to do to release `version-3` but there are some changes/fixes that I would like to do to `version-2` and I was wondering if it would be possible to go back to tag `version-2` make the changes (bug fixes) and then come back to where I left.

Is it possible to go back to tag `version-2` make some changes (bug fixes) create a new tag `version-2.1` release changes and then come back to where I left? If yes, what would be the process?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the `2.1` tag to sit on a commit which is in between 2 and 3 on the same branch?  Or would you be happy with a separate release branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be to create a branch from your tag:

```
git checkout version-2 -b branchname
```

To resume working on the new release, check out the master branch again:

```
git checkout master
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This would ordinarily be done by creating a version branch.

If you have a `v2.0` tag for version 2, create a new branch by naming the tag:

```
git checkout -b version-2 v2.0
```

If you don't have a tag, but you have a SHA 01234567...

```
git checkout -b version-2 01234567...
```

You can then switch back to your main branch with `git checkout`.

```
git checkout master
```

And go back to the version 2 branch with `git checkout`.

```
git checkout version-2
```

You can import changes from one branch to the other with `git merge` or `git cherry-pick`, depending on how you want to do things.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you will eventually resume working on the version-3 again after modifying the version-2

1. Commit your changes in the current branch( version-3)
2. git checkout .
3. apply your changes to this.
4. commit and push these changes to the remote repo.
5. now again checkout the version-3 and resume working

Another way if your changes are mid-flight and it will take a lot of effort to commit them to ensure your builds don't fail.

1. stash your current work on version-3 (git stash version-3)
2. checkout version-2
3. fix,commit and push the latest changes to version-2
4. checkout branch 3 (git checkout )
5. git pop the stashed away changes and carry on from where you left